# Perturbative method and Iterated integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, iterated-integrals

Consider the matrix ode $$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d t}(t)=x(t)A(t),x(0)=c$$where $x(t)\in\mathbb R^n, A(t) \in M_{n\times n}$ is continuous. It seems that we can use perturbative method (which I'm not sure if this is reasonable) to solve the matrix equaiton $Y_{\epsilon}(t)\in GL_n$
$$Y'_{\epsilon}(t)=\epsilon Y_{\epsilon}(t)A(t),Y_{\epsilon}(0)=I$$
where $Y_{\epsilon}(t)=I+Y_1(t)\epsilon+Y_2(t)\epsilon^2+\cdots$
In the end we get the following formula
$$x(t)=cY(t),Y(t)=I+\int_{0}^tA(t_1)dt_1+\int_0^t[\int_0^{t_2}A(t_1)dt_1]A(t_2)dt_2+\cdots\tag{1}$$
(a) In the Wikipedia page [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients) it says in general there is no closed form solution except the method [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion) using iterated commutators. I cannot see how Magnus expansion related to (1). Does iterated integral (1) has a name in ODE theory? Any reference or comment is appreciated!

(b) It seems that the perturbative method here can be generalized as follows, consider $Y(t)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal A$ where $\mathcal A$ is a completed graded algebra, while $A(t)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal A_1$, thus we can write homogeneous expansion $I(t)=\sum_0^{\infty}I_m(t)$ then the equaiton(the derivative here is point wise derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\otimes \mathrm{id}$)
$$Y'(t)=Y(t)A(t)$$ can also be solved as (1)! Is there a general context of this?

Comment: In physics this would be called the Dyson series for the time-ordered exponential.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How is Dyson series related to Magnus expansion mathematically? : )

Comment: The Magnus expansion tries to write the evolution operator as $e^{\Omega(t)}$, with no time ordering. The terms in the expansion of $\Omega$ can be related to the terms of the Dyson series. For the details look [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.5488)